# Remove surrounding Array and deliver one hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I have an Array as result of a query:

```
{"name"=>[{"en"=>"Title"}, {"de"=>"Titel"}]}
```

I wanna get the hashes of this Array and concat them **into one Hash**

So that my result is like that.

```
{"en"=>"Title", "de"=>"Titel"}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do:

```
hash = {"name"=>[{"en"=>"Title"}, {"de"=>"Titel"}]}
hash["name"].reduce(:merge) # => {"en"=>"Title", "de"=>"Titel"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Enumerable#reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) and the [`Hash#merge!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21) methods:

```
hash = {"name"=>[{"en"=>"Title"}, {"de"=>"Titel"}]}
hash['name'].reduce({}) { |result, h| result.merge!(h) }
# => {"en"=>"Title", "de"=>"Titel"}
```

Or in a slightly more efficient way using the [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) method:

```
hash['name'].each_with_object({}) { |h, result| result.merge!(h) }
# => {"en"=>"Title", "de"=>"Titel"}
```

The comparison:

```
require 'fruity'

names = [{"en"=>"Title"}, {"de"=>"Titel"}]

compare do   
  reduce do
    names.reduce({}) { |result, h| result.merge!(h) }
  end

  each_with_object do
    names.each_with_object({}) { |h, result| result.merge!(h) }
  end 
end
```

The result:

```
Running each test 1024 times. Test will take about 1 second.
each_with_object is faster than reduce by 30.000000000000004% ± 10.0%
```

Comment: I am always a fan of `#each_with_object`, when there `#inject` comes into the role. :) So +1